# How to verify contents of config file before running build in TeamCity

Tags: batch-file, find, teamcity

I would like to add a step to our `TeamCity` configuration that checks the contents of a `web.config` file.

If a key value isn't found, that means someone's checked it in with the wrong value and we shouldn't proceed with the build.
(TeamCity is running on a Windows server.)

I'm able to add a command line runner that executes the appropriate `FIND` command, but I can't capture the output from the `FIND` and use it within a subsequent `IF` statement.

Attempts to embed the FIND within a FOR statement have been unsuccessful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell runner:

```
$key = 'your-key'
[xml] $config = Get-Content path\to\web.config
$value = $config.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='$key']/@value")
if ($value.Value -ne 'your expected value') {
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple nant script using xmlPeek to check the value